# What are UEFI and BIOS?

Tags: boot, bios, grub, uefi

I have some difficulties to understand how the boot step of a computer works. Particularly the difference between BIOS and UEFI.

What I understand for now is UEFI is newer than BIOS. Both are some kind of firmware that boot the OS. I don't really want answer about how UEFI or BIOS works but rather explanation of the questions I have.

Are all computers now UEFI computers ? If a computer is an UEFI one, can it be a BIOS computer too ? What I mean is, does UEFI suppress BIOS or the two firmware can both be on the same computer ?

Even if we have a UEFI computer, the menu we can access by holding a key like F2 or F10 is called a BIOS menu ?

I also saw the term EFI. Is it different from UEFI ?

Linux distributions use GRUB to select which OS to boot on or which version. What does GRUB do compared to UEFI or BIOS ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

UEFI (Unified Extensible Firmware Interface) is just an upgraded version of the old bios interface.

BIOS (Basic Input/Output System) was made by a few companies (Phoenix, Award, American Megatrends) and all generally looked the same and could only be control with a keyboard.

UEFI are typically made by the manufacture that produces the motherboard. So ASUS have their own interface. Gigabyte will have something similar, but look differently. And gave you the ability to use a keyboard and mouse to control settings within the UEFI.

They are the same thing in respect to what it does for a motherboard.  Change configurations to suit your needs to how your computer runs or boots up.

UEFI allows way more customization, a better interface that allows novice users to be able to change settings without being confused as to what a certain setting does.

**Old looking bios.**

[image]

**New looking bios (or UEFI)**

[image]

[Video explaining the differences.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zIYkol851dU)

> Are all computers now UEFI computers ?

Yes. But only because motherboards now use only UEFI. I don't want to give you the impression that you can upgrade an older bios to a UEFI.

> If a computer is an UEFI one, can it be a BIOS computer too ? What I
>   mean is, does UEFI suppress BIOS or the two firmware can both be on
>   the same computer ?

No. You can only have 1 or the other. Modern Motherboards have UEFI, older Motherboards won't.

> Even if we have a UEFI computer, the menu we can access by holding a key like F2 or F10 is called a BIOS menu ?

Again, you keep thinking they are different things, when they are not. You access the UEFI (Bios) with which ever key is required of your motherboard.

> I also saw the term EFI. Is it different from UEFI ?

[The forum post is where I found this answer.](https://forum.level1techs.com/t/efi-vs-uefi/120216/3)

The UEFI specification will be based on the EFI specification (Extensible Firmware Interface) published by Intel with corrections and changes managed by the Unified EFI Forum. UEFI is meant as a replacement for the BIOS firmware interface, present in all IBM PC-compatible personal computers. In practice, most UEFI systems have legacy support for BIOS functions. The UEFI specification is managed by the Unified EFI Forum.

> Linux distributions use GRUB to select which OS to boot on or which version. What does GRUB do compared to UEFI or BIOS ?

GRUB is a boot loader for Linux. It is separate from UEFI or the Bios. You can access the UEFI regardless of operating system. A Bios controls the functions of your motherboard, a boot loader controls how the operating system will function.

Comment: Worth mentioning that if you have some software that requires BIOS and not UEFI (which is rarer and rarer nowadays), UEFI can look like a BIOS to software by using something called a CSM or "Compatibility Support Module."  Most operating systems can boot using UEFI and don't need CSM anymore.